# Jquery Attribute selector not cross browser?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, cross-browser

I got the below script:

```
$('.jcarousel li .views-field-title').each(function(index) {
    //alert(index+1 + ': ' + $(this).text());
    var idx=index+1;
    $('.jcarousel-navigation li[jcarousel-page='+idx+'] a').html($(this).text());
});
```

This is working like a charm in FF, IE7/8/9 but not on Chrome and Safari.

I understand it's because of the attribute selector.

Does anybody know how to make this script cross browser compatible? This looks like the only to do what I need to do.

Comment: Could you post your HTML as well?

Comment: Try taking the space out between li and .views-field-title so it's li.views-field-title

Comment: Did you try using an actual bonafied valid HTML attribute, like `data-jcarousel-page` ?

Comment: @adeneo: what you mean? My jcarousel comes from Drupal. Cannot change the markup.

Comment: Did a quick test, and it's working fine in Chrome for me : http://jsfiddle.net/u6QLF/1/

Comment: This probably means something else is wrong with your script, but all in all custom attributes like that are'nt really valid HTML, and data attributes used with a HTML5 doctype would be the preferred way to do this, if you could change the markup!

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to change the mark up at all. I read comments all around and look like this is a Webkit issue with the attribute selector in jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try enclosing the actual value in quotes, like this:

```
$('.jcarousel-navigation li[jcarousel-page="'+idx+'"] a')
```

Comment: attribute selectors without quotes work just fine in chrome, this is something else

Answer (score 1):

Try putting `idx` in quotes:

```
$('.jcarousel-navigation li[jcarousel-page="'+idx+'"] a')
```

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: attribute selectors without quotes work just fine in chrome, this is something else

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm the .each method is firing?

Have you tried taking out the space between li and .view-fields-title?

I.E

```
$('.jcarousel li.views-field-title').each(function(index) {
//alert(index+1 + ': ' + $(this).text());
var idx=index+1;
$('.jcarousel-navigation li[jcarousel-page='+idx+'] a').html($(this).text());
```

});

Comment: The commented alert is my debug code to confirm the .each method is firing. And it works. http://jsfiddle.net/jJ8tc/

Comment: Only on jsfiddle not on my environment.